# Contribution to the emblackening factor from massive gravitons

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I have been studying the effects of massive gravitons on the emblackening factor $f(r)$; i.e., given a Reissner-Nordstrom AdS geometry

$$ds^2=L^2 \left(\frac{dr^2}{f(r)r^2}+\frac{-f(r)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2}{r^2}  \right)\quad(\textrm{Eqn. } 1) $$
and
$$A(r)=\mu\left(1-\frac{r}{r_0}\right)dt\quad(\textrm{Eqn. } 2) $$
how does $f(r)$ change if we have an additional term in the action proportional to $m^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the graviton and $r_0$ is the black hole event horizon? The additional mass terms from the graviton are discussed [here ( "Holography without translational symmetry", by Vegh)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0537), and the end result is an emblackening factor given by Eqn. 26:

$$f(r)=1+\alpha F\frac{L m^2}{2}+\beta F^2 m^2 r^2-Mr^3+\frac{\mu^2}{4r_h^2}r^4\quad(\textrm{Eqn. } 3) $$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are proportional to the massive gravity term in the action, $M$ is the mass of the black hole, and the massive gravity action is given by $f_{\mu \nu}=\textrm{diag}(0,0,F^2,F^2)$. The derivation of this form appears to make sense to me, but I've also noticed a similar term discussed in [this work ("Solid Holography and Massive Gravity" by Alberte et. al.)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.09089), where Eqn. 5.5 yields

$$f(r)=1+\frac{\mu^2 r^2}{2r_h^2}+r^3\int^r dr' \frac{1}{r'^4}V(r')\quad(\textrm{Eqn. } 4)$$

where $V(r)$ is the background potential from the massive graviton.

My main question concerns the derivation of Eqn. 4, and how it relates to Eqn. 3. The two solutions look very similar; i.e., it seems as if the effects from the massive gravity term are simply added on to the AdS Schwarzschild solution. Therefore, would it be correct to say that, **for some general metric, the addition of a massive gravity background amounts to a constant term multiplying the emblackening factor?** If that is the case, how is Eqn. 4 derived? This seems unclear in the reference I linked. Is the additional term proportional to $V(r')$ due to Einstein's equations reducing to a set of  inhomogeneous differential equations? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have read them already but I think these lectures will provide useful information: http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ads-cft/L1.pdf (there are 5 of these lectures), though in a very compact way. Why is the factor called the emblackening factor? The same question applies to **black branes**. Why are they called that way? Are they emblackened because gravity doesn't reach infinity?